# How to use `std::async` to call a function in a mutex protected loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

```
vector<int> vecCustomers;
// populate vecCustomers

void funA()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard( _mutex ); // need lock here
    for(int i=0; i<vecCustomers.size(); ++i)
    {
        funB( vecCustomers[i] ); // can I run this asynchronously       
    }
}

void funB(int i)
{
    // do something here
}
```

Question> `funA` accesses critical resources and it uses the lock to protect the resources. `funB` doesn't use any critical resources and it doesn't need mutex. Is there a way that I can make use of `std::async` so that I can call funB and immediately return to prepare the calling next funB inside the loop? Also, before the return of the function, all tasks of funB must finish.

Thank you

== Update ==

I write the following code based on the suggestion. Now, the new issue is why all threads are blocked by the first thread?

The output is always as follows:

```
From[0]:H0 << why this thread blocks all others?
From[1]:H1
From[2]:H2
From[3]:H3
From[4]:H4


#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

struct ClassA
{
    ClassA()
    {
        vecStr.push_back( "H0" );
        vecStr.push_back( "H1" );
        vecStr.push_back( "H2" );
        vecStr.push_back( "H3" );
        vecStr.push_back( "H4" );
    }

    void start()
    {

        for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard( _mutex );
            std::string strCopy = vecStr[i];

            guard.unlock();
            std::async( std::launch::async, &ClassA::PrintString, this, i, strCopy );
            //PrintString( i, vecStr[i] );
            guard.lock();
        }
    }

    void PrintString( int i, const string& str) const
    {            
        if ( i == 0 )
            std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 10 ) );
        cout << "From[" << i << "]:" << str << endl;
    }

    mutex _mutex;
    vector<string> vecStr;
};

int main()
{
    ClassA ca;

    ca.start();

    return 0;
}
```

===Update 2===

```
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

struct ClassA
{
    ClassA()
    {
        vecStr.push_back( "H0" );
        vecStr.push_back( "H1" );
        vecStr.push_back( "H2" );
        vecStr.push_back( "H3" );
        vecStr.push_back( "H4" );
    }

    void start()
    {
        std::vector<std::future<void>> result;
        for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard( _mutex );
            std::string strCopy = vecStr[i];

            guard.unlock();
            result.push_back( std::async( std::launch::async, &ClassA::PrintString, this, i, strCopy ) );
            //PrintString( i, vecStr[i] );
        }

        for(auto &e : result) 
        {
            e.get();
        }
    }

    void PrintString( int i, const string& str) const
    {            
        static std::mutex m;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _(m);

        if ( i == 0 )
        {
            cout << "From[" << i << "]:" << str << " sleep for a while" << endl;
            _.unlock();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 10 ) );
        }
        else
            cout << "From[" << i << "]:" << str << endl;
    }

    mutex _mutex;
    vector<string> vecStr;
};

int main()
{
    ClassA ca;

    ca.start();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove that `guard.lock()` at the end of the loop.

Comment: The [fine documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async#Notes) explains why your modified version doesn't work.

Comment: Question: 1) Whatever that you are doing in funB to each customer (`vecCutomer[i]`), does that have to happen while doing funA? 2) Is funA(), called on the UI thread or some thread that runs code at a faster rate? If yes, it is funA that has to called asynchronously so that its doesn't block the rest of the thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primary reason you see the calls executed in order is that you aren't taking advantage of parallelism in any way (wait, what? but...). Let me explain

`std::async` doesn't just launch a task to be ran asynchronously, it also returns a `std::future` which can be used to get the returned value (should the launched function return something). However, because you do not store the future it is immediately destroyed after the task is launched. And unfortunately for you, in this case, the destructor blocks until the call is completed.

> [std::future::~future()] may block if all of the following are true: the shared state was created by a call to std::async, the shared state is not yet ready, and this was the last reference to the shared state.

([quote](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/~future)) Many people have expressed frustration due to this fact but that's how it is set by the standard.

So what you'll have to do is store the `std::future`s (in a vector or something) until all are launched.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly call `std::async` while keeping a mutex lock. The downside is that calling `std::async` takes some time thereby increasing the time you keep that mutex locked, and hence decreasing parallelism.

It may be cheaper to make a copy of that vector while holding the lock. Then release the mutex and process the copy asynchronously.

Your optimization objective is to minimize the time the mutex is locked and probably time spent in the function.

Comment: can you check my update? I don't know why the thread0 blocks all other threads even if I have launched all threads with std::async.